# Is it possible to somehow enable Performance and Metrics from DevTools protocol in Electron?

Tags: electron, puppeteer, chromium, chrome-devtools-protocol

I thought ElectronJS is using Chromium and it implies that it has all available implementation of the DevTools protocol.

For example Performance has stable api since version of the protocol 1.3 https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-3/Performance/

I'm using `puppeteer-core` to communicate via protocol and when I execute command via protocol

```js
const session = await browser.target().createCDPSession();
await session.send('Performance.enable');
```

I'm getting this error

```
ProtocolError: Protocol error (Performance.enable): 'Performance.enable' wasn't found
```

A lots of other commands are working fine, but not all of them, some are experimental like `Memory` https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Memory/ but it is there for quite a while.

---

Does electron some how disable some protocol APIs? In that case, how can I enable them again?

Or does electron ship its own custom chromium without some functionality that they consider undesirable(like Performance devtools protocol implementation)?